# How to run multiple SQL queries?

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a create table query, an update query ,and then drop table query. I need to run these three queries in one shot. What is the best way to do this?

```
Example
1st Query: Create table A.
2nd Query: Update value in table A
3rd Query: Drop table A.
```

Instead of running these three queries one by one, I want to run them in on go either by PLSQL or some other way. Please help.

Comment: Write the queries in a file (script) and then run the script: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/script.php

Comment: I did it in TOAD IDE. WE can run multiple queries at a time by pressing F5 I think(Done long back)

Comment: Also see this: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch6.htm

Comment: Sometimes you don't need the (temporary) staging table at all e.g. can use a CTE instead. But isn't the net result of running all three (create A, update A, drop A) exactly nothing?

Comment: Creating and dropping tables in a single Unit Of Work is a code smell.  It might be necessary in some other databases, but it is not necessary in Oracle: there are always better ways, depending on precisely what it is you need to do.

Answer (score 10):

Put the 3 queries following each other separated by a semi-colon:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_to_be_selected; 
DROP TABLE the table_to_be_dropped; 
TRUNCATE TABLE table_to_be_truncated;
```

You can concatenate these queries in a string and execute that string.

Answer (score 7):

Why not create a `PROCEDURE`?

E.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE foo
IS
BEGIN
  -- The create sentence goes here. For example:
  -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  -- 'CREATE TABLE bar (...)';

  -- The update sentence goes here
  -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  -- 'UPDATE bar SET ...';

  -- The drop/delete sentence goes here.
  -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  -- 'DROP TABLE bar;'
END;
```

You can test it with:

```
SET serveroutput ON;
exec foo;
```

The `PROCEDURE` is stored on the database, so you can use it later on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: don't forget about execute immediate for DDL statements here

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I learned something new today! :)

Answer (score 5):

Simply put three queries one after the other in a .sql file, with semi-colons after each statement, then execute it as a script (either on a SQL*Plus prompt using `@scriptname.sql` or in TOAD/SQL Developer [or equivalent] using its script execution function).