# How to run multiple queries on MySQL using PROCEDURE?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

What's the right way to create in MySQL a `PROCEDURE` for multiple queries like this one made for SQL?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE foo
IS
BEGIN
  -- The create sentence goes here. For example:
  -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  -- 'CREATE TABLE bar (...)';

  -- The update sentence goes here
  -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  -- 'UPDATE bar SET ...';

  -- The drop/delete sentence goes here.
  -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  -- 'DROP TABLE bar;'
END;
```

Comment: You don't need no `execute` statements. Just the queries seperated by `;`. Don't forget to set a different separator outside the procedure like `delimiter $`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: @juergend I saw this reply bad voted about it (that's the reason why I'm here) http://stackoverflow.com/a/6212730/4458531 What do you think?

Comment: @Simone: Don't know why. But I am not a PLSQL expert. In MySQL using just the queries is the way to go.

Comment: @juergend thanks, I don't understand the delimiter...should $ or // ...what's the difference?

Comment: Asking for the "right way" will result in an opinion. Are you looking for the MySQL recommended syntax for a `PROCEDURE`?

Comment: @Nathan I'm looking for the best option to run multiple queries at once in MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL just insert the 3 queries into your procedure. You need a different delimiter defined before, because otherwise the engine will terminate the procedure definition at the first `;` which would make it incomplete. So change to anything else like `$` or `//`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE your_proc()
BEGIN
  create ... ;
  update ... ;
  drop ... ;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo 
    @LastName nvarchar(50), 
    @FirstName nvarchar(50) 
AS 
    QUERY1; -- SELECT or whatever
    QUERY2;
GO
```

Comment: and maybe you should explain the final GO

Comment: SQL-Server uses `go`, MySQL not.