# Sharing user_id value between two MySql table

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, crud

I'm working on my middleware AuthController.js below. The middleware is part of a CRUD app. I created `exports.create` which when requested will collect the first name and last name from the CRUD form. Once collected the MySql `INSERT` query, will insert the data on the MySql `user` table which is working fine.

What I cannot achieve and I need help is that together with the first name and last name info I want to insert also the variable  `{ user_id: decoded.id }`, `decoded.id` is a variable which take the `user_id` value from another MySql table called `login`.

When I request `export.create` the following error shows on the terminal:

`(node:18780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: argument callback must be a function when provided`

Basically I want that the value under `user_id` column from the `login` table is transferred to the `user_id` column on `user` table. Thank for any help.

```
exports.create = async (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.cookies.jwt) {
        try {
            //1)verify the token
            var decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(req.cookies.jwt,
                process.env.JWT_SECRET
            );
            
            // console.log(decoded);
            const { first_name, last_name } = req.body;

            connection.query('INSERT INTO user SET first_name = ?,last_name = ?', { user_id: decoded.id }, [first_name, last_name,], (err, rows) => {
                if (!err) {
                    res.render('add-crew', { alert: 'Crew member added succesfully!' });
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);

            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return next();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connection.query` function takes in two to three arguments: the SQL statement, (the values) and the callback. Here, the function is taking four arguments, so it thinks `[first_name, last_name,]` is the callback.

What you can do is:

```js
...
connection.query('INSERT INTO user SET user_id = ?, first_name = ?,last_name = ?', [decoded.id, first_name, last_name,], (err, rows) => {
    if (!err) {
        res.render('add-crew', { alert: 'Crew member added succesfully!' });
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);
});
...
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

**Edit** you could also do:

```js
...
connection.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?', {user_id: decoded.id, first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name}, (err, rows) => {
    if (!err) {
        res.render('add-crew', { alert: 'Crew member added succesfully!' });
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);
});
...
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, it is EXACTLY what I was looking for. It's working perfectly, I went for the second option. I'm feeling retarded at the moment. I should have look more at the MySql documentation....I'm very grateful!

Comment: @CesareMannino no problem